# Continuity of a composite function

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $n=2$ or 3 and let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $T>0$ and $f \in L^2([0,T],H^1(\mathbb{R}^n))$.

Is the mapping
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{rcl}
C^0([0,T],C^1(\bar{\Omega})) & \to & L^2([0,T],H^1(\Omega))\\
\theta & \mapsto & f \circ (\mathcal{I} + \theta)
\end{array}
\end{equation}

continuous ?

EDIT : $\mathcal{I}$ is the identity mapping of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: What is $\mathcal{I}$?

Comment: $\mathcal{I}$ is the identity mapping of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Thank you for your remark, I edited the post.